# Declare 404 error even if the page does exist

Tags: php

I'm trying "CheckBot" and I have an observation. The problem is that in my PHP code I have an if to check if the URL exists in a table called "seo_url" if it does not exist then we show the content of error.tpl

```
<?php 

require_once 'app/config.php';

$url = isset($_GET["url"])?$_GET["url"]:'index';

$querytcseos = DB::queryFirstRow("SELECT * FROM tc_seos WHERE seo_url = %s LIMIT 1", $url);

  require_once 'includes/header.tpl';

  if (!$querytcseos['seo_file']) {
    include 'includes/error.tpl';
    } else {
    include 'includes/'.$querytcseos['seo_file'].'.tpl';
  }

  require_once 'includes/footer.tpl';

?>
```

I see that this does not seem to be the right thing to do since "CheckBot" when you enter example.com/page-not-fount if you are finding content.

How do I get my error page taken as error 404?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous in some parts but ultimately if you want to send a 404 at the application level you simply need to send a `404` response code to the client e.g. `http_response_code(404)`.

Comment: @Marty Then I can put <?php var_dump(http_response_code(404)); ?> in error.tpl and the robots will know that this is 404 error page?

Comment: Nah not like that - literally just call `http_response_code(404)` at the top of the script. You can inspect the response code sent by the server in Chrome's network tools.

Comment: @Marty Thanks, this seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

```
    http_response_code(404);
```

For best practice. You should respond it like that and let the server (Apache/Nginx/IIS) to handle the 404 page.